# Remove extra quotation marks in the grep output

Tags: regex, linux, bash

```
TUNNEL_TCP=$(grep -Po 'http:\/\/([\S]*?)"' ./tunnel_info.json )
```

the above cammand is used to get an http link
example: **www.224.ngrok.io**
but the output is say **www.224.ngrok.io"**

How can I remove the extra " at the end?

I tried editing the " from the grep command but it doesn't work.

Comment: to edit use `sed(1)`, and to filter lines use `grep(1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use positive lookahead:

```
grep -Po 'http:\/\/([\S]*?)(?=")'
```

`(?=")`matches the `"` without making it part of the match.

Comment: @user33207 Make sure you understand why, and let me know if you have questions. Best of luck!